# How to use openAPI generated typescript code in react app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web-applications

I'm making a webapp with React. For the backend I am using openAPI with Gradle to generate typescript for my API calls.

Right now, I have my frontend webapp done. And OpenAPI generates typescript files for my API.

However, what I do not understand is how to actually use the generated typescript files in my react app? I can't find any documentation on this online. This is what my setup looks like:

api.ts has following classes: ServiceApi ,ServiceApiFactory, UserData, UserDataResponse, ServiceApiAxiosParamCreator, ServiceApiFp

and I have my webpage.jsx,

when I import these classes I don't know what to do with them. When I try to do something like ServiceApi.functionName() I get an error saying the function does not exist, when it clearly does in the ts file.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create an instance of your api (optionally put a configuration in here to change the basePath of your backend)

```
const api = new ServiceApi();
```

Then you are able to call your service methods...

```
const result = await api.getWhatEverYourMethodNameIs();
```

There are a few blogposts describing that. For example one github repo is https://github.com/stefanwille/openapi-generator-typescript-example/blob/master/src/App.tsx

Comment: thank you i think this has done it but I am getting an axios 404 error.  createAxiosError (utils.js:151:1) at settle

Comment: Does your backend have swaggerui? Try your calls there and compare with the calls made by the generated client